# AmCharts Stacked Column Chart Left Alignment

Tags: jquery, amcharts

I want to move the chart result to the left, when data only appear on a column. I'm using AmCharts

I tried this not working

```
categoryAxis: {
                    gridPosition: "start",
                    parseDates: false,
                    gridAlpha: 0
                },
```

Is there any built in function? Please advise, thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add some extra data items with the category field empty:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "dataProvider": [{
        "category": "DC",
        "europe": 2.5,
        "namerica": 2.5
    }, {
        "category": ""
    }, {
        "category": ""
    }],
    ...
});
```

Please check the example here https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/7761bc970484780c536005c9ab79707f?editors=0010

Comment: thanks for the reply, maybe this is one of alternative. But i'm looking for an automatic left aligned, if it's possible